# Hotwire Rails - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails, turbo-rails

I have installed hotwire-rails in an existing Rails project. Before even writing any hotwire related code I get the following error on the browser console on every page:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` in `application.debug-86...95.js:53462`

The line that the error is referring to is this:

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
```

I am using Rails 6.1.3.1 with Sprockets for the assets, I have only used hotwire in Rails projects using webpack before so unsure if this has something to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the solution to your problem but I had the exact same error after removing webpack and installing importmap-rails in a recently updated Rails 7 app. But it was referring to my `application.js` imports statements, not a js controller.
Solved it by adding `type:"module"` to a `javascript_include_tag` I had in one of my layouts.
Final solution:

```
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', type: "module" %>
```

Or just delete the javascript_include_tag if you're already importing everything via `javascript_importmap_tags`

Comment: With webpack (moved from webpacker), this moved the problem to 'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "ol/Map". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".' which is `import Map from 'ol/Map';` in a JavaScript; not Stimulus (although I hope to move it there). Moving forward or sideways.

Answer (score -4):

In Rails 7, turbo comes prepackaged with a few gems that you need to install manually if you're using Rails 6.

1/ Install gem [importmap-rails](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails)

2/ Install gem [stimulus-rails](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails)

This should solve your issue.